# "Freeze" the slider

Tags: objective-c, nsslider

Is it possible to "freeze" the slider (NSSlider)? I'd like to make my slider unmovable (with a fixed value) when I press the button "Start", which starts my application... And when I press the button "Stop", which terminates my apllication, I'd like the slider to become movable again.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `enabled` property:

```
yourSlider.enabled = NO; // this will "freeze"
yourSlider.enabled = YES; // this will "unfreeze"
```